# Codeigniter Active Record vs Regular Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is regular MYSQL query faster than Codeigniter active record query? some where I read that the active record query takes memory to execute the query but regular not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Activerecord uses regular sql queries to perform whatever activities you want it to perform. Obviously, if you use activerecord to assemble the query on your behalf, then it may choose a less efficient way to do so, than you would.

This is a standard con against all current ORMs.

But the same query issued as raw sql and through activerecord will have the same performance impact even memory wise.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, "In the following examples does the second require *significantly* more memory?".

Example 1:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT `id`,`somefield` FROM `some_table` WHERE `id` = $id Order by `somefield` DESC");
```

Example 2:

```
$query = $this->db
          ->select('id, somefield')
          ->from('some_table')
          ->where('id, $id)
          ->order_by('somefield', 'DESC');
          ->get();
```

The answer is that the memory difference is not significant. There is some additional memory but, in the scheme of things, it's not a lot.

The purpose of Active Record (renamed Query Builder since CI v3) is to build a query statement string. The Active Record example **will execute a lot more code** to assemble the the same statement defined in the first example. After it constructs the statement it literally makes the exact same call the first example makes.

If the Active Record class is being loaded (determined by a database config setting) then memory is allocated to hold that code whether you use it or not.

Using Active Record does require a lot more typing. Why do that if the query is easily stated in a simple string?

On the other hand, in a situation where a different query statement might be conditionally required (i.e. different set of fields, additional or different "where" conditions, an alternate sort order, etc.) then Active Record can make your life a lot easier. For example.

```
$this->db
    ->select('id, somefield')
    ->from('some_table')
    ->where('id, $id);

if($need_another_where)
{
    $this->db->where('other_field', $other);
}

if($reverse_sort)
{
    $this->db->order_by('somefield', 'DESC');
}
else
{
    $this->db->order_by('somefield', 'ASC');
}

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Admittedly the above example could be recreated quite easily by conditionally concatenating a string. But more complex situations could easily exist.